# Docker variable expansion in compose entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've found that if I override an image's ENTRYPOINT in a docker-compose service entry, that it ignore variables defined in the environment section but will read them from an env file, e.g.

```
  someserver:
    image: "some-server:latest"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8849:8849"
    environment:
       javaMemoryLimit: 3056M
       JAVA_OPTS: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8849 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8849 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
    entrypoint: java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx${javaMemoryLimit} -jar /app.jar
```

When I do a `docker-compose up` with this I get warnings about variable not being set:

```
WARNING: The JAVA_OPTS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The javaMemoryLimit variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

But when I define the variable in an env file, e.g. .env

```
javaMemoryLimit=2098M
JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8849 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8849 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

Then variables are expanded as expected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Variables defined in the compose `environment` section are passed to the container, but not used by `docker-compose` itself to parse your yml file. The variables in the yml file are expanded with your host shell's environment (the shell where you run the `docker-compose up` command from) and/or the `.env` file contents.

Since you are running the entrypoint with the shell syntax, you can have the shell inside the container expand the variables instead of having `docker-compose` do it, by escaping the variables:

```
entrypoint: "java $${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx$${javaMemoryLimit} -jar /app.jar"
```

You may need to add a /bin/sh to parse those variables:

```
entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c \"java $${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx$${javaMemoryLimit} -jar /app.jar\""
```

Comment: I'm using version 2.1. of docker-compose and when I add those forward slashes I get an error: `ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a double-quoted scalar`

When I change the double quotes to single quotes, the variables are not populated, e.g. 

`    entrypoint: 'java \${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx\${JAVA_MEMORY_MAX} -jar /app.jar'
`

Comment: @KramKroc Sorry, used the wrong escape character. Needs to be a `$$` in docker-compose.yml instead of a `\$`.

Comment: This worked in the end for me @BMitch: `entrypoint: "bash -c 'java $${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx$${JAVA_MEMORY_MAX} -jar /app.jar'"`

Comment: Without the bash -c it didn't expand the variables.