# Docker variable expansion in compose environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've found that if I define an environment variable in a docker-compose service entry, that it will not be expanded in other variables defined in the environment section but it will be expanded if the variable is defined in an env file, e.g.

```
  someserver:
    image: "some-server:latest"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8849:8849"
    environment:
       javaMemoryLimit: 3056M
       JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx${javaMemoryLimit} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8849 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8849 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

When I do a `docker-compose up` with this I get warnings about variable not being set:

```
WARNING: The javaMemoryLimit variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

The same occurs if I use the list form of environment definition.

But if the variable javaMemoryLimit is defined in a .env then the expansion is fine. I've also tried using `$$javaMemoryLimit` and then I don't get the warning message but the variable is not expanded when the container actually starts. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of the question from yesterday? You need a shell to expand the variable. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48184700/596285

Comment: I can see why you might think that it's the same question. This is different though and in this case I've no entrypoint defined in the compose file. 

I'm defining additional variables to use within other variables that are used in the dockerfile and the ENTRYPOINT in the dockerfie is taking care of variable expansion, e.g. I've something like `ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c", "java \${JAVA_OPTS} -jar app.jar" ]`

Comment: Did you try removing the `\\` in your entrypoint?

Answer (score 4):

This is deliberate variable substitution behavior. Only `.env` and variables from the shell environment are evaluated at the `docker-compose.yaml` level. Otherwise, `${javaMemoryLimit}` will expand to an empty string.

As a side note: even more annoying is the fact that NO variable substitution whatsoever is done in files specified by`env_file:`.

That said, if you do `"-Xmx$${javaMemoryLimit} -D...` whatever expands `JAVA_OPTS` might work since that should expand to `-Xmx${javaMemoryLimit} -D...` (instead of `-Xmx -D...`) in your `ENTRYPOINT`.